# Use FPDF to create a table with cells which contain normal text and superscripts

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to create a table in a PDF using FPDF and the header needs to have both normal text and superscripts in the same cell.

Here's my table:

```
$this->Ln();
$html='<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="70" height="30">Header</td>
        <td width="200" height="30">Header</td>
        <td width="200" height="30">Header</td>
        <td width="70" height="30">Header<sup>1</sup></td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

I'm using the [WriteHTML extension class](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php).  I changed the OpenTag function to include the case for SUP below.

```
$this->WriteHTML($html);    

case 'SUP':

     $subFontSize=6;
     $subOffset=4;

     // resize font
     $subFontSizeold = $this->FontSizePt;
     $this->SetFontSize($subFontSize);

     // reposition y
     $subOffset = ((($subFontSize - $subFontSizeold) / $this->k) * 0.3) + ($subOffset / $this->k);
     $subX        = $this->x;
     $subY        = $this->y;
     $this->SetXY($subX, $subY - $subOffset);

     break;
```

I added the code below to the CloseTag function

```
if($tag == 'SUP')
{
    $subOffset=4;
    // restore y position
    $subX        = $this->x;
    $subY        = $this->y;
    $this->SetXY($subX,  $subY + $subOffset);

    // restore font size
    $this->SetFontSize($this->subFontSizeold);          
}
```

I can not figure out how to combine the text and superscript into one cell of width 70.  I'm getting two cells both with a width of 70.  This is what it looks like:

[image]

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I've updated the table to this

```
$html='<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="70" height="30">Gene</td>
        <td width="200" height="30">DNA</td>
        <td width="200" height="30">Protein</td>
        <td width="70" height="30" padding="0" margin="0">VAF</td>
        <td width="3" height="30" padding="0" margin="0"><sup>1</sup></td>
        <td width="80" height="30" padding="0" margin="0">COSMIC</td>
        <td width="3" height="30" padding="0" margin="0"><sup>2</sup></td>
        <td width="70" height="30" padding="0" margin="0">Tier</td>
        <td width="3" height="30" padding="0" margin="0"><sup>3</sup></td>
    </tr>
</table>';
```

I also updated the OpenTag function to

```
case 'SUP':

    $subFontSize=6;
    $subOffset=4;
    $this->tableborder = '';
    // resize font
    $subFontSizeold = $this->FontSizePt;
    $this->SetFontSize($subFontSize);

    // reposition y
    $subOffset = ((($subFontSize - $subFontSizeold) / $this->k) * 0.3) + ($subOffset / $this->k);
    $subX        = $this->x-5;
    $subY        = $this->y;
    $this->SetXY($subX, $subY - $subOffset);

    break;
```

And the CloseTag function to:

```
    if($tag == 'SUP')
    {
        $subOffset=4;
        // restore y position
        $subX        = $this->x+4.15;
        $subY        = $this->y-3;

        $this->SetXY($subX,  $subY + $subOffset);

        // restore font size
        $this->SetFontSize($this->subFontSizeold);  
        $this->tableborder = 'TBLR';
    }
```

Which produces what I need however, I'm unsure how to automatically put the superscript closer to the word.

[image]

Comment: In Some cases, this might happens due to padding and margin of table tag.
try with padding and margin 0.

Comment: This does not work.  The 4th td is actually being written 2 times to the PDF since cell is being called twice.  I'm unsure how to call Cell only once for both of these.

Comment: there are a lot of tags those don't work in fpdf have you confirmed that sup is working in fpdf?

Comment: Yes it is in FPDF and it actually works well outside of the table however, inside the table it is adding two Cells.